# Ignoring Exceptions in Object Oriented Programming

Tags: oop, exception

In some applications, I came across some lines of code which deliberately eats the exceptions. In my application the benefit of doing this is - To ignore the exception and just continue with the loop(The exception handled is for an error thrown inside the loop). The following lines of code looks evil to even an experienced developers. But is sensible to the context(I mean, that is the requirement - to process all the files in the directory).

```
try{
    //some lines of code which might throw exception
}catch(Exception e){
    //no code to handle the error thrown
}
```

What other benefits can ignoring exceptions provide?

Comment: What is OOPS? What language are you talking about? Anyway, this question is too broad.

Comment: Yes. I have this doubt in the applications I work for(RoR and Java).

Comment: Down Voter: Is this a question which really wastes your time analyzing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a requirement to process all the files, if you get an exception during processing one of them, is not the requirement broken already? Either something failed or the exception is not needed.

If you want to continue the processing **handle the exception, then continue**. Why not just report the problem with processing a given file,so someone can later process it manually?  Probably even stupid `cerr << "Hey I had trouble with this file '" << file <<', so I skipped it.\n"` would be better than nothing.

Exception is there to signal something. If you are ignoring it either you are doing something nasty, or the exception is not needed.

The only valid reason for ignoring the exception I can think of is when someone throws exceptions at you for no good reason. Then maybe, yeah, ignore.

Comment: Thanks luk32 for responding. I know this is wrong. But I want to know if there is any benefit of just ignoring the exceptions.

Comment: You got 4 answers saying that plainly ignoring is a very bad practice. Hmm... positives. Ok, you wrote less code. Ok, maybe if you process 1k tasks and only 5 of them will break you will get the 99,5% of work done. However you will not get whole work done, and you will need to find what w"nt wrong and why anyways. Why not spare the trouble? I feel that my `ignore when someone throws it at you for no reason" is Zaheer's answer, but really bad worded :)

Comment: @luk32 +1 for `cerr << "Hey I had trouble with this file '" << file <<', so I skipped it.\n"`

Comment: Well, I ate an exception once, out of laziness. I had regretted this decision =)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there any any benefits of ignoring exceptions.  It will only cause problems. If you want the code to be executed in the loop, after handling it, it will continue with the loop because exception is handled. You can always process the files in your directory even if you are not doing anything after handling exceptions.

It will be better if you write some log regarding the files for which exception is thrown

If you eat the exception. You may never know what is the actual cause of the problem.
Considerr this example

```
public class Test {

    private int x;

    public void someMethod(){

        try {
             x = 10/0;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.someMethod();
        System.out.println(test.x);
    }

}
```

This will print simply `0` the default value of x as exception occured during division and value was not assigned to `x`

Here you are supposed to get actual result of the division. Well it will definitely throw an `ArithMeticException` because we are dividing by zero and we have not written anything in catch block. So if the exception occurs, nothing will be printed and value of x will be 0 always and we can't know whether the division is happend or not. So always handle exceptions properly.

Comment: Thanks for your illustration. Your response is really useful :)

Answer (score 1):

This is generally the mark of bad code - you always want to handle your exceptions by at a minimum reporting what the exception is. Ignoring exceptions will let your program keep running, but generally exceptions are thrown for a reason and you or the user need to know what that reason is. Doing a catch-all and escaping just means the coder was too lazy to fix whatever problems cropped up.

The exception is if the coder is throwing exceptions merely to pass arguments, which is something I saw on DailyWTF once.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we should not absorb the exception but there can be reason like there is a function which is out of business logic that is just to help some kind of extra functionality, then you do not want your application to break if that function throw the exception in that case you absorb/eat the exception. But I do not recommend the empty catch block, one should log this in ELMAH or other error logging tools for future.

Comment: Well, if the called code was well designed should not the "extra functionality" exception be handled in the appropriate places within the module? I kind of dislike the vision of stray exceptions leaking out 'casue something did not converged, or something was not found and we need to fallback to some other method. But it indeed is a valid reason to ignore it.

Comment: if it is then go for it. If due to exception (if occurs) ur app breaks then handle it.